# When testing a strategy, how to extract the date (range) of a certain order range on the X Axis? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here's a good example for a test result showing fallbacks to be identify. To identify what might cause the fallback, we should know what happened then so we should be able to know when the certain fallback occurred, to know what kind of event our strategy reacts wrong to.

[image: Strategy Test Result Chart with fallbacks to be identified]

There's no data on mouse over (it would be the best, I guess, if we should consider it a feature request), no relevant useful menu item in the right-click context menu. **Is there a way to tell the strategy to attach & show** `date` **data on the Test Result Chart?**

(Of course, in this case, we can know the reason of the fallback, it's just an example to those cases when we can't identify them.)

Comment: Is the "List of Trades" tab not useful?

Comment: Huh, that's a 6000-lines huge sheet, and there's no re-arrange or filter options. The only hope is that, we can download it as CSV so eventually it can be processed. I check it out how. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpPgb.png

Comment: Yep, arranging the sheet by Drawdown column, we can see something, although it's more cumbersome than it could be.